# Adding Multiple JSON Layers to Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to put two different json files over a single map. One is drawn by zip code boundaries, the other is county. For some reason, I can't get my leaflet to work. IF someone can help point me to where the issue lies, that'll be great!

```
   <script>
   //ingest and congiure zip file
   zipjson = L.geoJson("zip-file.json", {
     style: style,
     onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
       layer.on({
         mouseover: highlightFeature,
         mouseout: resetHighlight,
     })
       layer.bindPopup('<b>Zip Code: </b>' + feature.properties.ZIPCODE + '<br>' +
       "<b> Data Attribute #1: </b> " + feature.properties.attr1 + '<br>' +
       "<b> Data Attribute #2: </b> " + feature.properties.attr2 + '<br>' +
       )
     }
   }).addTo(map);

   //ingest and configure county level layer
   countyjson = L.geoJson("county-file.json", {
     style: style,
     onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
       layer.on({
         mouseover: highlightFeature,
         mouseout: resetHighlight,
     })
       layer.bindPopup('<b>County: </b>' + feature.properties.COUNTY + '<br>' +
       "<b> Data Attribute #1: </b> " + feature.properties.attr1 + '<br>' +
       "<b> Data Attribute #2: </b> " + feature.properties.attr2 + '<br>' +
       )
     }
   }).addTo(map);

   // set map layer
   var usmap = L.tileLayer('mapbox.streets', {
       maxZoom: 18,
       minZoom: 1,
       attribution: '<font size = "2"><b> Target Universe:  Voters who voted in the last two caucus plus the top 100k modeled voters</b></font><br>'
   }).

   L.mapbox.accessToken = 'fake-token-name';

   //initalize map
   var map = L.mapbox.map('map',{
     center: [41.9, -91.5],
     zoom: 7,
     layers: [usmap]
   });

   //set parameters to color map
    var max_num = 2000;
    var color = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, max_num])
          .range(['#F0F0D0', '#930F16']);

    function style(feature) {
      return {
          fillColor: color(feature.properties.targetnum), // fill depending on value
          weight: 1,
          opacity: 0.5, 
          color: 'black',
          fillOpacity: 0.9 
      };
    }


    // configuration to fix map
    var baseMaps = {
      "US" : usmap,
    };

    var overlayMap = {
      "Counties" : countyjson,
      "Zip Codes" : zipjson
    };

    L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMap).addTo(map);

   </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities I found (I have had the same problem).

1. For the first one, the answer on top help. I was trying to do it as you did, without using the `<script>` tag to load the files, but if you do so, it works. Declare each JSON file using the `<script>` tag:

```html
<script src="JSONFILE-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JSONFILE-2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure each JSON file starts with the the `var` declaration, as it will be included through the script tag:

```js
var jsonVar = { "type":"Feature"...
```

Call them in:

```js
var layer1 = L.geoJson(var_name_from_jsonfile1, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      radius: 8, ...
                });
  }
});
var layer2 = L.geoJson(var_name_from_jsonfile2, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      radius: 8, ...
                });
  }
});
```

When calling them, you do not need to `addTo(map)` since this will be taken care of, as you did on your code, by   `L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);`.

2. If you don't want to include the files as such and would rather use `$.geojson` I found another option which is just calling the `L.geoJson` with `null`. It works just as well (though I don't know if its the most elegant solution):

```
var jsonVar = L.geoJson(null, {...
```

...then:

```
$.getJSON("json/nead.json", function (data) {
      jsonVar.addData(data);
    });
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Tel, I do have a question. When you declare the JSON files with the script, do you keep the files as `.json` or convert it to `.js`?

Comment: I have used either, they both work.

Comment: did you get it to work for you?

Comment: Sadly, no it didn't work. I'm having issues with mapbox returning a certain error `ReferenceError: feature is not defined`. For some reason, passing it in through your suggestion (choice #1), I can't pass extra arguments to fill in the color appropriately.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907595/mapbox-popup-referenceerror-features-is-not-defined and try checking your .json in http://geojsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

You shoud add your external geojson files as standalone scripts and then reference their variable name within your leaflet script.

```
<script>
L.geoJson(zipData).addTo(map);

var map = L.mapbox.map('map',{
   center: [41.9, -91.5],
   zoom: 7,
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="zip-file.json"></script>`
```

Your zip-file.json should start something like

`var zipData = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[....`

This page shows a good example of an external file being used
http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON data should refer to a variable if possible-i.e "county-file.json" should be instead 
let countydata =*add the data here*