# Fetching the leaflet map with plain JSON data

Tags: leaflet, javascript, json

countnuing the problem from this query:

[Import pure (regular) JSON file to Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342339/import-pure-regular-json-file-to-leaflet)

I have trouble with input the plain .json data to the leaflet map. I tried 2 ways to do this:

1. I attached the .json code as a JavaScript variation:

   ```
     var bv = {
    "Sheet1": {
   "-430524279882": {
    "MDU_ID": -430524279882,
     "Status": "Invoiced",
    "THP": 12,
    "Latitude": 52.41635,
    "Longitude": -1.55227
     },
      "-430532279893": {
     "MDU_ID": -430532279893,
     "Status": "Invoiced",
     "THP": 12,
     "Latitude": 52.41635,
     "Longitude": -1.55227
      },
      "-430622279798": {
      "MDU_ID": -430622279798,
      "Status": "Invoiced",
      "THP": 12,
      "Latitude": 52.41555,
     "Longitude": -1.55155
      },
       "-430519279894": {
      "MDU_ID": -430519279894,
       "Status": "Invoiced",
      "THP": 12,
      "Latitude": 52.41635,
      "Longitude": -1.55227
       },
       "-430558279922": {
      "MDU_ID": -430558279922,
      "Status": "DO NOT DESIGN - SDN",
      "THP": 5,
      "Latitude": 52.41635,
      "Longitude": -1.55227
      },
      "100071574860": {
      "MDU_ID": 100071574860,
      "Status": "DO NOT DESIGN - SDN",
      "THP": 5,
      "Latitude": 52.41555,
      "Longitude": -1.55155
       },
       "-430564279884": {
       "MDU_ID": -430564279884,
       "Status": "DO NOT DESIGN - SDN",
       "THP": 5,
       "Latitude": 52.41635,
       "Longitude": -1.55227
      },
       "-435086278038": {
       "MDU_ID": -435086278038,
      "Status": "Invoiced",
      "THP": 10,
      "Latitude": 52.39908,
       "Longitude": -1.4861
       },
       "-476625255228": {
       "MDU_ID": -476625255228,
       "Status": "Invoiced",
       "THP": 6,
       "Latitude": 54.18998,
       "Longitude": -3.88052
      }
    }
   };
   ```

and next:

```
   var myPointsLayer = L.featureGroup(bv);
   for(var key in data2.Sheet1){
   var latLng = L.latLng([data2.Sheet1[key].Latitude, 
   data2.Sheet1[key].Longitude]);
   L.marker(latLng).bindPopup(data2.Sheet1[key].Status).addTo(myPointsLayer);
  }
```

My 2nd way was:

```
var url = 'bv.json';

var laya = $.getJSON(url);
var myPointsLayer = L.featureGroup(laya);
for(var key in data2.Sheet1){
  var latLng = L.latLng([data2.Sheet1[key].Latitude, data2.Sheet1[key].Longitude]);
  L.marker(latLng).bindPopup(data2.Sheet1[key].Status).addTo(myPointsLayer);
}
```

Both not working:

Console says:

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: data2 is not defined
>     at (index):119
```

whereas data2 belongs to my .json file.

Is there any way to populate this stuff on the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a lack of some basic understanding of methods and object used in the above attempts.

In the first attempt there is attempt to create a feature layer with call `L.featureGroup(bv);`, where `bv` is JSON object. A look at the Leaflet docs at https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#featuregroup shows that parameter for this method is an array of layers, not JSON object. Then there is reference to `data2` object, which is not defined anywhere and which should be JSON object.

So the first attempt should look something like:

```
var markerGroup = L.featureGroup([]).addTo(map);

for(var key in bv.Sheet1){
  var latLng = L.latLng([bv.Sheet1[key].Latitude, bv.Sheet1[key].Longitude]);
  L.marker(latLng).bindPopup(bv.Sheet1[key].Status).addTo(markerGroup);
}
```

In the second attempt JSON is retrieved from file with AJAX call `$.getJSON`. Here the following is wrong:

- There is no wait for completition of AJAX data retrieval, data is used immediately after the call;
- JSON object is pased as parameter in `L.featureGroup(laya)` call, when parameter for this method should be an array of layers;
- `data2` object is referenced, which is not defined anywhere, it should be JSON object.

The second attempt should look something like this:

```
var markerGroup = L.featureGroup([]).addTo(map);

$.getJSON('bv.json', function(data) {
  for(var key in data.Sheet1){
    var latLng = L.latLng([data.Sheet1[key].Latitude, data.Sheet1[key].Longitude]);
    L.marker(latLng).bindPopup(data.Sheet1[key].Status).addTo(markerGroup);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's good. What I still don't understand is: Why in the L.featureGroup([]) we set nothing instead of  L.featureGroup([bv]). The L.featureGroup([bv]) command is not working, but in my point of view is such a constradiction to the: L.featureGroup([marker1, marker2, polyline])? as well as here: L.featureGroup(<Layer[]> layers)|?

Comment: Because at the beginning `L.featureGroup([])` is empty. As I wrote, it can take as input parameter only array of existing Leaflet layers, and `bv` is not a layer but JSON object.